# Is it inefficient to be change the data of a VBO for every polygon?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, opengl-3

I'm building an OpenGL wrapper. Right now, right now VBOs seem like the only options for modern OpenGL development. Now, of course the API I'm trying to create doesn't exactly work like that. The design has to be something like `graphics.draw(GL_TRIANGLES, verticies)`, and not something requires handles. Anyway, I'm trying to avoid using the FFP since it's long gone these days but I'm wondering if VBOs are any good at this. Of course it wouldn't be nearly as effective, but I'm worried it might not do good at all (too slow). What I was going to do was swap all data out every time a something is drawn with the new data and call the VBO again. Is this effective at all (not slower then Immedient Mode)? Nothing is performance critical.

Comment: Immediate mode (also known as `glBegin/glEnd`) is long gone, and was slowest way to draw. If you rewriting VBO each time, it's no better then ordinary vertex arrays (same `glDrawElements`, but without VBO). Just noted - you want separate call for each polygon? Not for each submesh? That will be sloooooow in any case.

Comment: Again, it's not performance critical, it's supposed to be easy to work with. I'm not testing the theory of relativity here, it's for 2d graphics. I'm just wondering if it's inefficient to use compared to anything else available in the older versions.

Comment: If you don't care about speed, why would you want to use harder solution? Which may (and most likely will) result in even slower execution.

Comment: Harder? Compared to what solution?

Comment: To vertex arrays. Same thing, but without VBO creating/data filling. As for immediate mode, i do not know it's performance, but it may be comparable with single polygons (although still unadviced to use it as deprecated feature. But rendering one polygon per call is unadviced too)

Comment: @keltar: You cannot propose that immediate mode is gone and then advertise *client-side vertex arrays* as an alternative - they're both legacy functionality and should *not* be used, especially in new code.

Comment: @user2896590: What version of OpenGL are you targeting? It matters, because a VBO doesn't cut it starting with GL 3.2.

Comment: @keltar: Also, VBOs and client-side vertex arrays are sure as shootin' not the same thing - at all.

Comment: @thokra depends on version. immediate removed since 2.0, VA - 3.1. anyway, it doesn't matter with one poly per call

Comment: I think it is relevant to know which data you are going to swap, and why. As opengl is low-level, similar goals may require vastly different tools.

Comment: @keltar: Nonsense. Immediate mode was non-deprecated core until GL 2.1 - just like vertex arrays. Both were removed from core with GL 3.1 - and that's exactly why it matters. If you write a core GL 3.1+ application, you simply can't use that stuff, independent of the poly count.

Comment: @thokra right. It appears i bear too much with ES, sorry. As for polycount, i meant it needs to be chained into larger buffer, with textures merged into atlas. Not too GL-related tho. But anyway, your latest comment is the only possible answer to this question.